# CryptoJS DES in ECB mode

Tags: javascript, cryptography, des, cryptojs

I'm dealing with a third-party gateway that requires DES ECB with PKCS1 padding. So this code is not for my own use, but to send the message to the other guys.

Before you ask how come they're using symmetrical-key encryption on the internet: I first must send  them symmetrical key encrypted with SHA algorithm and only then encode the message with the DES key.
This is NOT MY IDEA doing it. But it's very important for my project etc.

I will do my own padding function, so please don't point me on NoPadding option. This code is just to test if DES works fine on my side.

I'm facing a weird (for me) behavior of the crypt-js module in node.js
Here's the code:

```
var C = require('crypto-js'),
    source = 'abcdefghabcdefgh',
    key = '1234test';

var encrypted = C.DES.encrypt(
    C.enc.Utf8.parse(source),
    C.enc.Hex.parse(key),
    { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }
).ciphertext.toString();

var decrypted = C.DES.decrypt(
    C.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: C.enc.Utf8.parse(encrypted) }),
    C.enc.Hex.parse(key),
    { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }
).toString();

if (source === decrypted) {
    console.log('Glad :)');
} else {
    console.log('Sad :(');
}
```

The code won't turn glad this way.
Crypto-JS and all other modules are the latest versions.
Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: `g` and `h` are invalid in hexadecimal, isn't it the problem?

Comment: DES and ECB are each insecure. Use AES and CBC.

Comment: This is not my decision. It's the third party that I'm dealing with.

Comment: Yeah. Correct. C.enc.Hex.parse parses only hex strings. But how do I encode and decode utf8 text?

Comment: Don't parse the `source`? Note that the source needs to be a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: Okay... and what to do with encrypted then?

Comment: You need to either use an encoding like base 64 or hex or send the bytes directly, i.e. without using `toString`.

Comment: Ok there's a function C.enc.Utf8.parse(source) in the crypto-js module. But how do I parse the response?

Answer (score 3):

This one did it for me, works perfectly: https://gist.github.com/ufologist/5581486

Comment: Would you mind if I copy the code here? (To prevent data loss in case gist deleted.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see it, you have two issues:

1. `key` is Utf8 and must be `parse`d this way,
2. `ciphertext.toString()` is actually a string that contains the Base 64 encoded ciphertext, so you need to parse it as `Base64` during decryption.

As Maarten Bodewes said in the comments, since you are using no padding, you have to ensure that your plaintext is a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: var encrypted = C.DES.encrypt(
    C.enc.Utf8.parse(source),
    C.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
    { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }
).ciphertext.toString();

var decrypted = C.DES.decrypt(
    C.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: C.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted) }),
    C.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
    { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }
).toString();

Doesn't work either