# Decrypt string DES-ECB using cryptojs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I tried using [this](https://encode-decode.com/des-ecb-encrypt-online/) online tool to decrypt my string and it works perfectly fine, which I want to implement in my React app.

encrypted string: "iPPGVzyogeiPwpro65A0eUaQggN+8+J4mteJdeaEeFiCL4nTGWnI3F16SIjtZBIxsc7WJNlKm0HtZ754aGgzDIPzFaL/aK97"

decrypted string: "http://aac.saavncdn.com/666/487fc075363611f93bb2a8bfc27635f6_96.mp4",

When I'm trying to code this the encrypted string comes out different if I try to encrypt and vice versa

Here is my code:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(
      "http://aac.saavncdn.com/666/487fc075363611f93bb2a8bfc27635f6_96.mp4",
      "38346591"
    ).toString();
```

this gives a different output:
U2FsdGVkX18ql9OPbTS4FRRHvl8Tvm7m2Vg5SkUdIM2p9OF6GU0wYmJQoitwGoPlKCx8tTfdcLGNc34V3sgw1EKlCeSYtJ6LFc2BDpdfNOw3XYoadapisA==

```
var encrypted =
      "iPPGVzyogeiPwpro65A0eUaQggN+8+J4mteJdeaEeFiCL4nTGWnI3F16SIjtZBIxsc7WJNlKm0HtZ754aGgzDIPzFaL/aK97";

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(encrypted, "38346591");
    console.log(decrypted.toString());
```

that's why the decrypt also doesn't work.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46587521/128761) help?

Comment: Thank you so much, I made this new account just to ask this bcuz in my previous ac i can't ask anymore questions bcuz of so many downvotes.