# decryption DES with ECB using Crypto-es expo project

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, jsx, cryptojs

I have asked this question before for React [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631349/decrypt-string-des-ecb-using-cryptojs).

I'm using [crypto-es](https://github.com/entronad/crypto-es) which is based on CryptoJS.
I've used this is react like this

```
function decryptByDES(ciphertext) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("38346591");

    // direct decrypt ciphertext
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(
      {
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext),
      },
      keyHex,
      {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
      }
    );

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
```

However using the same function in react-native gives me this error:
[image]

Test data:

encrypted text: "ID2ieOjCrwfgWvL5sXl4B1ImC5QfbsDycMwuqSNl+oXFQYM2ahEKHjJ8S9AMOijqZzashfXSBli0hxaWMyCdjhw7tS9a8Gtq"

expected decrypted result: https://aac.saavncdn.com/881/374283a91cd721f65f59e3a49e6f5623_96.mp4

secret key: 38346591

Comment: Please share some test data, i.e. besides the key also ciphertext and expected plaintext.

Comment: It could be this CryptoES bug: [#22](https://github.com/entronad/crypto-es/issues/22).

Comment: @Topaco I've added test data to the original post.

Comment: Nvm i used an older version of crypto-js ^3.3.0 which works fine with react-native